# Postgresql Update JSON Column Retaining Some KeyValues and Adding Additional KeyValue as null

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to use a `metadata` JSONB column for a multi-tenant application.  Every `user` for each tenant must have the same `metadata`, but the tenants have varying `metadata` fields.

In order to keep all user metadata in sync per tenant, when the tenant admin modifies the metadata fields I need to make sure all users have their metadata JSONB column updated with the following criteria:

1. If the metadata field/key already exists, the value needs to be retained
2. If the metadata field/key is new, the key needs to added with a null value
3. If there are any metadata fields/keys that are not included in the updated list, they should be deleted from the JSON object

For example, all the users for Tenant #1 have the following metadata assigned: `{ "EmployeeNo" : 123, "HireDate" : "2012-10-10", "Age" : 43 }` and somewhere down the line the admin decides they don't care about Age, but they do want to start tracking ParkingSpace.

I need the new metadata record to retain the EmployeeNo and HireDate values, remove the Age key/value, and add the ParkingSpace key with a null value. `{ "EmployeeNo" : 123, "HireDate" : "2012-10-10", "ParkingSpace" : null }`.

I would have thought that I could run an update query similar to the following where it returns a JSONB object where it selects the values if the key exists and a null if it doesn't:

`UPDATE users SET metadata = metadata[keys: 'EmployeeNo', 'HireDate', 'ParkingSpace'] WHERE tenant_id = 1;`

Obviously that won't work, but hopefully it indicates the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: I might have misunderstood your question. Maybe you wanted something like that instead:

```
UPDATE users
SET metadata = (SELECT json_object_agg(n,metadata->>n) FROM unnest(ARRAY['EmployeeNo','HireDate','ParkingSpace']) AS t(n))
```

This solution involves creating a brand new jsonb object by extracting only the field that you want from the original `metadata`. The fields to be copied over are specified as an array that you can easily customize.

**Original answer**: I think this should do it:

```
UPDATE users
SET metadata = (metadata - 'Age') || '{"ParkingSpace": null}'::jsonb;
```

I am using the `||` operator which merges 2 jsonb objects into one and the `-` operator which removes a key/value pair.

Comment: I could probably make that work, ideally I'd like to not have to keep track of the columns being removed (in this case 'Age').

Comment: I reread your question and I updated my answer. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Sweet, your updated answer seems to work perfectly!  Now I'll have to look through the docs on *why* it works (particularly the json_object_agg and the unnest array).  Thanks!